# Customizing search result for only some of the results

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

How can I change or customize search results for only some sorts of list items (belonging to a specific list) so that when you click on the result it does not open the list item but my application page?

Comment: How well versed are you in XSLT? You'll probably have to do some matching so that any result coming from your specified list has its own display template.

Comment: I am not so good in XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Customize search result types in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135239(v=office.15).aspx) and [SharePoint 2013 Design Manager display templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138(v=office.15).aspx#bk_createDT).

You could create a custom display template, perhaps using */_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default.html* as your starting point, and change it so the links open your application page.

Then you could create a Result Type with a condition that matches your list, perhaps you can have it match the Path of your list, and an action that uses your custom display template.